# How to get key of elements in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am an absolute beginner in Android and Firebase. Forgive me for my post. I want to get the key element that is under "node" eventos. Till I have done the following code, but I am no able to get the key. Please help me, I am doing my college project.

```
DatabaseReference mDataBase =  `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`
                DatabaseReference usuarios = mDataBase.child("usuarios");
                DatabaseReference eventos = usuarios.child("eventos");

                eventos.orderByValue().equalTo("eventos").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            String key = snap.getKey();
                            System.out.println("LAS CLAVES SON: "+key);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
enter code here
                    }
                });
```

I want to get the key to update each element and delete.

[image]

Comment: What property of each element you want to update?

Comment: what issue are you having with the getKey() ? Is that not working ?

Comment: i want to update whole properties and later

Comment: Gastón, it's show me "W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": ".value"' at usuarios/eventos to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance"

Answer (score 0):

you have to just remove your some code :-

```
eventos.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            String key = snap.getKey();
                            System.out.println("LAS CLAVES SON: "+key);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
enter code here
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Sandeep Malik, i want to get  key by each element for update and delete. The code you answered, these give me whole keys's are availiable inside node 'eventos'. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: you can store these key in arrayList and after that update and delete the element of keys